# Are there ways to populate a schema in Joi from another schema (like Mongoose does)?

Tags: mongoose, mongoose-schema, mongoose-populate, joi

I'm currently only using Joi to validate and building schemas.
However I feel like I'm missing features like reference another schema like Mongoose does.

Or is the only way to do this by using both (or mongoose only)?

I want to use something similar to this:

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const Schema = mongoose.Schema;

const personSchema = Schema({
  _id: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
  name: String,
  age: Number,
  stories: [{ type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'Story' }]
});

const storySchema = Schema({
  author: { type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'Person' },
  title: String,
  fans: [{ type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'Person' }]
});

const Story = mongoose.model('Story', storySchema);
const Person = mongoose.model('Person', personSchema);
```

But in Joi instead. I cannot find anything in the Documentation for Joi.

Comment: Please describe what you want to do in other terms than mongoose. Look into joi.concat in the meantime.