# How to efficiently model objects for ArangoDB?

Tags: javascript, nosql, arangodb

I'm new to ArangoDB and javascript (and pretty much everything else too). I'm watching a tutorial that uses Vue, GraphQL, Mongoose and MongoDB. I would like to use a very similar technology stack, except with ArangoDB.

However, when using Arangojs (the javascript driver for ArangoDB), I find myself having to work a lot harder and write a lot more code to accomplish the same thing compared to the tutorial, and this difference comes down to Mongoose. I'm looking for a solution or development approach that will allow easy evolution and maintenance of the code base, above all else.

In particular, when defining a Mongoose schema, we can do things like this:

```
const UserSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
username: {
    type: String,
    required: true,
    unique: true,
    trim: true
},
    //...
favorites: {
    type: [mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId],
    required: true,
    ref: "Post"
}
});
```

The `ref` type provides a lot of convenience, for example. I guess I'm looking for something like Mongoose for ArangoDB and javascript, but I don't think such a thing exists. So I'm asking how (at a high level) can I approach my development to achieve a similar level of coding functionality.

For example, can GraphQL's SDL schemas achieve the same thing as a Mongoose Schema, and nearly as easily?

Is there a way to use a GraphQL schema across both the frontend and backend of a javascript application, eliminating javascript typeDefs and models in the process? The goal here, as suggested above, is to prioritize ease of working with the code as features are added and changes made to the project requirements.

Update: this looks like a similar question (without an answer):

[Are there ways to populate a schema in Joi from another schema (like Mongoose does)? - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54254097/are-there-ways-to-populate-a-schema-in-joi-from-another-schema-like-mongoose-do)